# my magento website's layout has been changed after using flat catogry and product setting on and off

Tags: php, html, magento, layout

Just for knowledge I turned *use flat catalog category* and *Use Flat Catalog product* settings on but my website layout has been changed. So I turned it off but it is not changing back as it was. What should i do?

I did these settings on and off

```
system->configuration->catalog->Use Flat Catalog Category
system->configuration->catalog->Use Flat Catalog Product
```

I turned both of these on and off but my website's layout is not like before.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Thanks for replying!! Yes I did but it's not working..

Comment: Anyone please help I think something is wrong with my layout and template...what should i do?

Comment: Are you sure that the layout changes due to the changes that you have mentioned above? because it doesnot seem that the above changes should reflect in the layout changes. Have a look, whether the site is using your theme or not. Check whether you have made some changes in your design tab in admin panel. You can set the template path hint "on" to check whether it is rendering from correct theme or not. Hope this will work.

Comment: I changed Current Configuration Scope also but now layout is not the same now let me know what should i do?

Comment: Have you checked which theme the site is rendering right now. Use this to check https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_themes.htm

Comment: Yes I have checked everything. My app and skin folders' permissions were 777  so i think something has changed in code but i am not getting how to restore my page layout like before it was.